# Output something once per request

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a module that exports a method that can may be called several times by any code in node.js using it. The method will be called usually from views and it will output some html/css/js. Some of this html/css/js however only needs to be output once per page so I'd like to output it only the first time the module is called per request. I can accomplish doing it the first time the module is called ever but again the method of my module can be called several times across several requests for the time the server is up so I specifically want to run some specific code only **once per page**.

Furthermore, I want to do this while requiring the user to pass as little to my method as possible. If they pass the request object when creating the server I figure I can put a variable in there that will tell me if my method was already called or not. Ideally though I'd like to avoid even that. I'm thinking something like the following from within my module:

```
var http = require('http');
http.Server.on('request', function(request, response){
    console.log('REQUEST EVENT FIRED!');
    // output one-time css
});
```

However this doesn't work, I assume it's because I'm not actually pointing to the Server emitter that was/may have been created in the script that was originally called. I'm new to node.js so any ideas, clues or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a variable on the request is an accepted pattern. Or on the response, if you don't even want to pass the request to your function.

One more thing you can do is indeed, like you write, have the app add a middleware and have that middleware either output that thing.

Comment: That's what I thought I would have to do but I was trying to avoid that. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your "problem" but what you are trying to achieve seems to me like building a web application using Node.js. I think you should use one of the web frameworks that are available for Node so you can avoid reinventing the wheel (writing routing, static files serving etc. yourself).

Express framework is a nice place to start. You can find tons of tutorials around the internet and it has strong community: http://expressjs.com/